# Style a table as a tic tac toe board with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I am planning to write a tic tac toe game with jQuery and PHP. I want to style the board (an html table) with CSS. I am not aware of CSS properties that can be applied to selectively to cells so that specific cells get borders. 
Are there any CSS properties that I can use or should I try a different approach instead?

The html markup is:

```
  <div id="board">
    <table>
      <tr id="row1">
        <td class="square"></td>
        <td class="square"></td>
        <td class="square"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row2">
        <td class="square"></td>
        <td class="square"></td>
        <td class="square"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row3">
        <td class="square"></td>
        <td class="square"></td>
        <td class="square"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, add a second class to some TDs and give borders only to that class.

HTML and CSS:

```css
.square{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.v{
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}

.h{
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
    <table>
      <tr id="row1">
        <td class="square"></td>
        <td class="square v"></td>
        <td class="square"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row2">
        <td class="square h"></td>
        <td class="square v h"></td>
        <td class="square h"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row3">
        <td class="square"></td>
        <td class="square v"></td>
        <td class="square"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: This renders perfectly in jsFiddle and Safari/Chrome but not in Firefox or IE, is there some fix for this?
FYI I'm running IE9 and Firefox 5.

Answer (score 0):

Say you wanted the middle square to have a black border, simply do this:

```
.middle {
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
<td class="middle"></td.>
```

Comment: Oh and forgot to mention, if you want to keep the class square, simple do this:

`<td class="square middle"></td>`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to give multiple classes to each td, except the middle square. 
for example, the vary first td, would have class 'top' and 'left' and in your css top would have border-top: none; and left would have border-left: none; and square would always have all borders.

Comment: forgot to mention, you'd keep the square class for each td.